# Angularjs Directive's link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm confused about using angularjs directives.

directive need scope @header , so I write like below.

But, I can't get $scope.text data from the child controller in the link function.

So, I remove

```
                  scope : {
                          navi : '@header'       
                        },
```

this from  directive, then I can get $scope.text data.

Why it happened?

```js
 about.js it belong to about.html

angular.module('sampleAngularApp')
  .controller('AboutCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    
    var nTxt = $(".location>a:eq(0)").text();
 var lTxt = $(".location>strong").text();
 console.log(lTxt);
    $scope.$emit('text',{
     sub : nTxt,
     lub : lTxt
    });
  }]);
```

```html
 about.html it involved in ng-view

<div class="content">
 <div class="location">
  <a href="/business/toastbarAds">About</a> &gt; <a
   href="/business/instPopup">설치제휴</a> &gt; <strong>Daum 시작페이지</strong>
 </div>
 <p>This is the about view.</p>
</div>
```

```js
app
  .directive(
    "headerMenu",
    function() {
     return {
      restrict : 'E',
      template : '<header class="header"><h1><a href="../prod/funcMain.html"><span class="blind">AhnLab Insight Portal</span></a></h1>'
        + '<nav class="gnb"><ul><li class="ico name">'
        + '<li><a href="#/logout">Logout</a></li>'
        + '<li class="last"><a href="#/help">Help</a></li>'
        + '</ul></nav><nav class="navi">'
        + '<ul><li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>'
        + '<li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>'
        + '<li><a href="#/business">Business</a></li>'
        + '</ul></nav></header>',
      link : function(scope, element, attr) {
       scope.$on('text', function(event, data) {
        console.log(data);
        scope.header = data.sub;
        scope.lnb = data.lub;
        angular.element(".navi ul li a").each(
          function() {
           var nTxt = data.sub;
           if (nTxt == angular.element(this)
             .text()
             || nTxt == '')
            angular.element(this).addClass(
              "selected");
          });
       });

      }
     };
    });

app
  .directive(
    "leftMenu",
    function() {
     return {
                        scope : {
                          navi : '@header'       
                        },
      restrict : 'E',
      transclude : true,
      template : '<a href="#" class="btnFold"><span class="blind">lnb 영역 접기/펴기 토글</span></a> '
        + ' <nav class="lnb"><ul ng-show="navi == \'Home\'"><li>'
        + ' <a href="../prod/funcMain.html">기능사용 분석</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../prod/funcMain.html">메인UI</a></li>'
        +'<li>'
        + ' <a href="../prod/pattChk.html">사용패턴 분석</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../prod/pattChk.html">최근검사</a></li>'
        + ' <li><a href="../prod/pattUpda.html">업데이트</a></li>'
        + ' <li><a href="../prod/pattStay.html">체류시간</a></li>'
        + ' <li><a href="../prod/pattMenu.html">시작메뉴</a></li>'
        + ' <li><a href="../prod/pattPage.html">시작페이지 도메인</a></li>'
        + ' </ul></li></ul>'
        + '<ul ng-show="navi == \'About\'" id="customer"><li>'
        + ' <a href="../cust/instDele.html">설치/삭제분석</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/instDele.html">설치/삭제</a></li>'
        + ' </ul></li><li>'
        + ' <a href="../cust/place.html">설치제휴</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/place.html">Daum 시작페이지</a></li>'
        + ' </ul>'
        + '</li>'
        + '<li>'
        + ' <a href="../cust/custType.html">고객상태 분석</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/custType.html">고객상태별</a></li>'
        + ' </ul>'
        + '</li>'
        + '<li>'
        + ' <a href="../cust/b2bType.html">신규고객 분석(B2B)</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/b2bType.html">업종별</a></li>'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/b2bUser.html">유저구간별</a></li>'
        + ' </ul>'
        + '</li>'
        + '<li>'
        + ' <a href="../cust/prodOver.html">자사중복사용분석</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/prodOver.html">중복사용현황</a></li>'
        + ' </ul>'
        + '</li>'
        + '<li>'
        + ' <a href="../cust/searchNum.html">고객 상세조회</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/searchNum.html">제품번호 조회</a></li>'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/searchVer.html">제품버전 조회</a></li>'
        + ' <li><a href="../cust/searchUser.html">고객현황 조회</a></li>'
        + ' </ul>'
        + '</li></ul>'
        + '<ul ng-show="navi == \'Business\'" id="business">'
        + '<li>'
        + ' <a href="../busi/bnToast.html">광고제휴</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../busi/bnToast.html">토스트바배너</a></li>'
        + ' </ul>'
        + '</li>'
        + '<li>'
        + ' <a href="../busi/instPage.html">설치제휴</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../busi/instPage.html">Daum 시작페이지</a></li>'
        + ' </ul>'
        + '</li>'
        + '<li>'
        + ' <a href="../busi/servPcReco.html">서비스제휴</a>'
        + ' <ul class="sub">'
        + ' <li><a href="../busi/servPcReco.html">PC복구</a></li>'
        + ' <li><a href="../busi/servV365.html">V3 365서비스</a></li>'
        + ' </ul>' + '</li></ul></nav>',
      link : function(scope, element, attribute) {
      
                           // It doesn't work!!
       scope.$on('text', function(event, data){
        scope.navi = data.sub;
        var lTxt= data.lub;
        angular.element(".lnb .sub li a").each(function() {
         if (lTxt == angular.element(this).text() || lTxt == '')
          angular.element(this).parents('li').addClass("selected");
        });
       });
             
                          });
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <header-menu></header-menu>
   <div class="container">
    <left-menu header={{header}}></left-menu>
    <div ng-view></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Any fiddle for your problem ?

Comment: Check your console, I get a syntax error in your code.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see?  Could you remove everything from your example except what is needed to show the issue (i.e. 90% of your template)?